# Ram upgrade causes black screen but dmidecode command indicates is possible do upgrade

Tags: linux, laptop, memory, motherboard, upgrade

I did do an upgrade for 3 laptops about RAM, 2 of them have Linux (Ubuntu and Peppermint) and was executed the dmidecode command, for a HP according with its official specs the max capacity is 8GB but the dmidecode command indicated 16GB, so with that information was upgraded in peace to 16GB

Now for an old Acer Aspire One:

- KAV60 LO3 (according with the slot for the RAM)

The same dmidecode command indicates the following:

```
sudo dmidecode -t memory
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.4 present.

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 5, 20 bytes
Memory Controller Information
    Error Detecting Method: None
    Error Correcting Capabilities:
        None
    Supported Interleave: One-way Interleave
    Current Interleave: One-way Interleave
    Maximum Memory Module Size: 2048 MB
    Maximum Total Memory Size: 4096 MB
    Supported Speeds:
        Other
    Supported Memory Types:
        Other
    Memory Module Voltage: Unknown
    Associated Memory Slots: 2
        0x0000
        0x0000
    Enabled Error Correcting Capabilities:
        None

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 4 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 1

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
    Socket Designation: J2
    Bank Connections: 0 0
    Current Speed: 1 ns
    Type: DIMM
    Installed Size: 2048 MB (Single-bank Connection)
    Enabled Size: 2048 MB (Single-bank Connection)
    Error Status: OK

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0016
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 2 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: J2
    Bank Locator: CHAN A DIMM 0
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 533 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 0x0000000000000000
    Serial Number: 0x00000000
    Asset Tag: Unknown
    Part Number: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Well I bought this RAM

- [A-Tech 4GB DDR2 800MHz SODIMM PC2-6400 1.8V CL6 200-Pin Non-ECC Unbuffered Laptop RAM Memory Upgrade Module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00C53AZQY)

But sadly when the laptop is started it remains with the black screen.

The removed stick is:

```
#
# Box
#
Golden Memory
GM800D2S6/2G
2GB PC2-6400 CL6 200-Pin SODIMM

#
# Sticker in the RAM itself
#
GM800D2S6/2G
DDR2 200 PIN SODIMM 1.8V
```

What would be possible to do to get working this 4GB in peace?

Comment: Have you tried going to a website to help select the correct memory, e.g., https://www.kingstonmemoryshop.co.uk/ or https://www.crucial.com/ to see if that RAM is compatible with the PC??

Comment: Yes, the mentioned model does not appear. Because is DDR2 technology

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the laptop has a memory controller that was designed to support two SODIMM slots, although the laptop manufacturer did not wire up the 2nd slot in your particular model.

With that in mind, the dmidecode output indicates that the limit is only **2 GB per slot**, and the 4 GB number is actually the total limit across **both** slots. Since your laptop physically has only one slot, 2 GB is the highest you can get.

Google says that KAV60 LO3 typically goes with a 32-bit Intel Atom CPU, so it probably won't be worth trying to upgrade it above 2 GB anyway – with most programs that require this amount of RAM, it's the CPU that won't be able to keep up. (In theory, the extra RAM could be useful for page cache to speed up file access, but you'll probably get a better result from upgrading the HDD to an SSD.)

Comment: Yes, I already have a SSD of 1TB ready to be installed, but I want the pair working in peace. I mean 4GB and 1TB SSD. Therefore I want first resolve this about the RAM. I assumed a BIOS upgrade would be the solution

Comment: It's more likely to be the controller physically missing the circuitry to handle more address bits, than anything software-related.

Comment: Is there a special command through Linux to confirm "It's more likely to be the controller physically missing the circuitry to handle more address bits"? ...

Comment: No, it really isn't. `dmidecode` can give results based on characteristics that don't actually exist in a specific motherboard, as explained here.